# why I use fetch to upload img in react don't have fileName?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, web, fetch

I use fetch to upload images in react,my code is like below:

```
    let formData = new FormData();
    let file = {uri: imgdata, type: 'multipart/form-data', name: '2_resources.jpg'};
    formData.append("name", "name");
    formData.append("mobile", "18381307123");
    formData.append("content", "123654");
    formData.append("resources", file,"2_resources.jpg");//mind this line
    fetch(Config.report,
        {
            mode: 'cors',
            method: "POST",
            body: formData
        })
        .then(res => res.json())
        .then((data) => {
                console.log(data)
            }
        ).catch((err) => {
            console.log(err)
        }
    );
```

but,run it I get the request :
[image: the request]

I have look for `FormData` API document on https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData
it have write below:
[image]

and the fetch used is :`"isomorphic-fetch": "^2.2.1"`

what should I do to use fetch upload images? thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You are adding the file to the FormData object incorrectly. isomorphic-fetch wraps github's fetch polyfill. Looking at their [docs](https://github.com/github/fetch#file-upload) shows that it should be:

```
handleFileUpload(event) {
  var formData = new FormData();
  formData.append('fileName', event.target.files[0]);
  fetch('http://your-domain/upload',
    {
      mode: 'cors',
      method: 'POST',
      body: formData
    }).then(function (response) {
   console.log('response: ', response);
  });
}
```

The field name on the server will be whatever you use as the key when appending formData. In the above example it will be 'fileName'. I also don't think you need to set the content-type and file name yourself. It should get set automatically.

In the above example, 'event' is the event fired from the input tag when the user upload the file:

```
<input type="file" onChange={this.handleFileUpload}/>
```

Comment: thanks,I know how to fix it,I use [ant design](https://mobile.ant.design/components/image-picker-cn/#components-image-picker-demo-basic) to picker image  and use it incorrectly. thank you very much.